# sfdx is removing metadata from permission sets when changing read/write to false

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, sourcecontrol

I updated some permissions sets in my package and change some field-level security access to read/write false for some objects.

When I run `sfdx force:source:pull` instead of marking the XML as

```
<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>false</editable>
    <field>Some_Object__c.Some_Field__c</field>
    <readable>false</readable>
</fieldPermissions>
```

it removes the reference entirely. So when I push this to a different org the values do not change.

Is there a setting for "preserving" metadata instead of deleting it when read/write access is false?

Comment: I think the command to fetch metadata is 'retrieve' and not pull.

Comment: @VishalSharma it's pull, you're thinking of the mdapi commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point there is no such setting. I suggest opening up an enhancement request for this [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli)

> When you retrieve permission sets, the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm) asks the developer to retrieve the related components with assigned permissions.

The way `force:source:pull` works is it only retrieves items thats incremented with RevisionCounter in [SourceMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sourcemember.htm) object. Currently it only sees permissionset.

For now you can workaround this using the `sfdx force:source: retrieve` below so you don't have to manually craft the XML. Note that this won't source track, however run sfdx `force:source:push` to make sure it is tracked.

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m PermissionSet:<permissionsetname1,permissionsetname2>,CustomField:<objectname1>.<fieldname1>,<objectname1>.<fieldname2>
```

Next time the `force:source:pull` will not remove those XML elements after you push.